# Hdfs + solr installation error cannot create core collection1

Tags: java, hadoop, solr

Am trying to implement search engine over HDFS with Solr I have installed Hadoop Successfully but while am configuring Solr am getting some error... Am very new to Solr Please help on on this

solrconfig.xml

```
 <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory" class="solr.HdfsDirectoryFactory">
      <str name="solr.hdfs.home">hdfs://127.0.0.1:10001/home/hadoop/hadoop-datastore/tmp/dfs/solr</str>
      <str name="solr.hdfs.confdir">/home/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/conf</str>
    <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.enabled">true</bool>
      <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.slab.count">1</int>
      <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.direct.memory.allocation">true</bool>
      <int name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.blocksperbank">16384</int>
      <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.read.enabled">true</bool>
      <bool name="solr.hdfs.blockcache.write.enabled">true</bool>
      <bool name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.enable">true</bool>
      <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxmergesizemb">16</int>
      <int name="solr.hdfs.nrtcachingdirectory.maxcachedmb">192</int>
    </directoryFactory>
```

Please let me know what is the mistake i maid on this file

Am trying to start Solr with please let me know this is correct or not

```
java -Dsolr.directoryFactory=HdfsDirectoryFactory -Dsolr.lock.type=hdfs -Dsolr.hdfs.home=hdfs://127.0.0.1:10001/home/hadoop/hadoop-datastore/tmp/dfs/solr -Dsolr.hdfs.confdir=/home/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/conf -jar start.jar
```

Error Message while starting

```
  ERROR org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Unable to create core: collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Problem creating directory: hdfs://127.0.0.1:10001/home/hadoop/hadoop-datastore/tmp/dfs/solr/collection1/data
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:834)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:625)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:557)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:592)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:271)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:263)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem creating directory:     hdfs://127.0.0.1:10001/home/hadoop/hadoop-datastore/tmp/dfs/solr/collection1/data
at org.apache.solr.store.hdfs.HdfsDirectory.<init>(HdfsDirectory.java:68)
at org.apache.solr.core.HdfsDirectoryFactory.create(HdfsDirectoryFactory.java:154)
```

Am using Hadoop 1.2.1

Please help me on this to start up this search functionality

Comment: This indicate issue with protobuffer incompatibility with version of protobuffer HDFS using versus SOLR. Though im still trying to find how to fix this

Comment: I was a problem with missing jars. I kept all jar in a single directory and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever may face similar issue in future.

It may be caused by several things. Check these:

1. Make sure that correct HDFS NameNode hostname / port are used. In OP's configuration it's `hdfs://127.0.0.1:10001`, but default port for NN RPC is 8020.
2. Make sure to add configuration into solrconfig.xml. It should both have `<directoryFactory>` and `<lockType>hdfs</lockType>`.
3. When using Solr with HDFS data directory is described in `<directoryFactory>` block, so default `<dataDir>` should be commented out.
4. User `solr` should be owner of solr data root directory on HDFS. This could be messed up if collection was created using CLI under root or hdfs user.